# How to listen to javascript events in ChromiumFX using C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium

I am currently working with ChromiumFX browser control as below.

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumfx/chromiumfx/src

Now I have to listen to every single javascript events which are fired in the browser.

I have tried some events from the api reference document.

https://chromiumfx.bitbucket.io/api/html/T_Chromium_Event_CfxOnJsDialogEventArgs.htm

This gives me events when only alert fired.

My point is that

1. Whenever javascript function is fired, it should pass the function's name to browser control, So I can find out which function was called in browser

I have not found any information about this event handler in that api reference web site.

Has anyone have tried this before?